# How does c store a double decimal in an 8 bit slot?

Tags: c, double, decimal

How does c store a double decimal in an 8 bit slot?

```
#include "stdio.h"

main(){
  double x = 123.456;
  printf("\n %d - %e \n",sizeof(x),x);
}
```

outputs:

```
8 - 23.456
```

The value of x is correct being 123.456, but the supposedly it is only 8 bits.

Comment: `sizeof` returns a `size_t`, which should technically be printed with `"%zu"`. If your compiler is good (and you turn your warnings up) it will probably give you a warning about that. (Also, `main() { ... }` kind of hurts to see, even if it's legal.)

Comment: @ChrisLutz: `main() { ... }` is legal in C90, but illegal in C99.  Of course `int main(void) { ... }` is preferable in both.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's not 8 bits. It's 8 bytes. And each byte is at least 8 bits (and usually exactly 8 bits).

So it's probably 8 * 8 = 64-bits for a `double`.

EDIT:

The `sizeof()` operator yields the size of an object *in bytes*.

A "byte" is by definition the size of a `char`.  (That's how the C standard defines the word "byte"; it may have different meanings in other contexts.)

The number of bits in a byte is specified by the macro `CHAR_BIT`, defined in `<limits.h>`.  Almost any system you're likely to encounter will have `CHAR_BIT == 8`, but I understand that some implementations for DSPs (Digital Signal Processors) have `CHAR_BIT` set to 16 or 32.

Comment: Do you know of any articles that explain how decimals are stored in c?

Comment: If you mean "decimals" as in floating-point, then just see the wikipedia article: (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point) It's actually stored in binary.

Comment: Technically, each "byte" is `CHAR_BIT` bits, so `sizeof(double) * CHAR_BIT` is the number of bits a `double` is stored in. (In practice, it's almost always going to be 64 of course.)

Comment: @Chris Lut: Yeah, I just looked it up on wikipedia and realized that a "byte" is not actually defined as 8-bits. (even though it seems like it always has been)

Comment: I've just edited the answer to correct the use of terminology.  A char *is* exactly one byte; that's how the C standard defines the word "byte".

Answer (score 2):

To be horribly pedantic `sizeof` return the size of the operand in multiples of `sizeof char`.

On all common platforms that means that `sizeof` returns in bytes.

Comment: To be more pedantic, there is no fixed definition of "byte" (it does not have to be an octet), and some would define it as equivalent to the size of a `char`.

Comment: @MatthewFlaschen: The C standard defines a byte as the size of a char (which is at least 8 bits).

Comment: Exactly, the term is historical. Back when the first microprocessors came about, they would chew on 8-bit 'bytes' of data at once. An 8-bit byte had just enough flavour to convey something worthwhile.